# Soft Taekwondo introduction for other people

Tags: tae-kwon-do, teaching

I was wondering what kind of exercise would be good to introduce a few Taekwondo techniques to other people, for example, colleagues during a company annual meeting, or similar conferences.

As a comparison, I've seen facilitators have a short session of simple exercises, before starting the afternoon sessions. I'm told there are business schools teaching that practice, to help raise people's attention level for the remaining sessions.

I'm thinking of short sessions of 10-15 minutes, not more than 20 minutes.

So, adapting this to Taekwondo, what kind kind of exercises we could introduce? Some ideas I have at the moment are:

- Warn up joints: neck, shoulder, elbow, wrists, hips, knees, feet.
- Basic kick: *ap chagui* / front kick, maybe *bandal chagui*
- Basic wrist escapes.

Any ideas or advice?

Comment: What length of session is this for? (approach would vary a lot if its 10 mins or 30 or 60).
I'd also check with your association what you are covered to teach in such sessions (and check what is covered by works insurance etc.) Don't put yourself at unnecessary risk (sue culture being what it is these days)

Comment: Added that detail to the question: in my experience should be 10-20 mins max. And yes, should be low intensity and low risk, and suitable to all sizes and ages. I've seen people doing jumping jacks, but I personally wouldn't go that far.

Comment: Would you have everybody participate, or just a couple of volunteers up on stage? There are a lot of inflexible and overweight people over 40 or 50 I work with who I definitely wouldn't want to see do jumping jacks. Apart from concerns like that, you and I would find presentations like this interesting to lead, and to experience if we were transported back to our pre-MA days, but in my experience a lot of people would have absolutely zero interest in it, and a very few would have a negative reaction ("I don't want to think about fighting!").

Comment: I would like to include everyone, as much as possible. It should be leisure and uplifting moment, and not a challenge or real exercise.

Comment: I would avoid kicking. You're going to have a wide variety of footwear and balance abilities. Stick with something *everyone* can do and feel good about. You don't want to embarrass anyone right before a meeting.

Comment: This is an opinion based question. More of a call for discussion than anything. But I'll add my 2 cents. No contact. No hard stuff. Gotta be easy. No bag work. No kicks. That leaves you with some real basic stuff. I'd teach them something like a simplified first form. You learn the ready position. You learn the front stance and how to step forward and turn in it. You learn the down block and front punch. Then you learn how to combine them and step in a "+" formation similar to chon-ji hyung. Takes about 15 minutes to learn. And that is their first, simplified form. Add ki-hap for bonus points.

Answer (score 4):

Teach exercises that build into small sequence, that two participants can work together.

Example exercises:

1)Round-house kick
2)Jab-cross combo
3)Kick block
4)high punch guard

sequence:

1st person perform 1-2, 2nd person reacts with 3-4 and adds a push, then they switch roles - 2nd  person perform 1-2, 1st person reacts with 3-4 and adds a push, and so on.

- Safety is above everything. build it so untrained person will not injure his training partner. You can tell them to kick low, and use open palms instead of punches because "they are not trained yet".